# Android Asset Package Manager (appt) is not found

Tags: android-studio

I am in correct directory (OSX Sierra)

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3
```

I use `ls` and see `aapt`, but when I run the `aapt`executable, this error results

> -bash: aapt: command not found

Why is appt not found though I am executing from correct directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the terminal doesn't have direct access to the executables in the current working directory. The absolute path appears to work:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt
```